# How to deploy multiple react app in netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, netlify

I am trying to deploy multiple react apps in netlify on same url.

For example:

Main react app is present on `https://example.netlify.app`

Another react app is present on `https://example.netlify.app/app-one`

Another react app on `https://example.netlify.app/app-two`

A netlify app takes github repo as base to deploy the website.

How do I use to same repo or perhaps separate repos for apps and deploy it on same netlify url?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in 3 steps.

1. Make structure like this.

   - root

     - app-one

       - (app-one files and folders)
     - app-two

       - (app-two files and folders)
     - main-app

       - (main app files and folders)
2. In `root` directory create `netlify.toml` file.

   Edit it like below.

   [[redirects]]
   from = "/app-one/*"
   to = "/app-one/index.html"
   status = 200

   [[redirects]]
   from = "/app-two/*"
   to = "/app-two/index.html"
   status = 200

   [[redirects]]
   from = "/*"
   to = "/main-app/index.html"
   status = 200

   [build]
   command = "npm run build"  // this is based on your build script
   publish = "main-app/build"  // this is based on your build output directory
3. Deploy on Netlify:
   For each app, create a separate site on Netlify.
   Link each site to its respective folder (e.g., app-one, app-two, main-app).
   Deploy each site.
   Now, you can access your apps using the specified paths:

   https://example.netlify.app/app-one

   https://example.netlify.app/app-two

   https://example.netlify.app

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try this!